# XSD How to generate sequence/record number in a unbounded field?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD with a field called "customer" that is minOccurs=0 and maxOccurs=unbounded.   Is there a way to attach a sequence number to that customer entry automatically?

Ideally the generated XML would look like:

```
<customerupdate>
<customer record="1">
<fname>albert</fname>
</customer>
<customer record="2">
<fname>david</fname>
</customer>
</customerupdate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do what you want.

You can only define a default or fixed value for attributes, but only static values can be assigned to default/fixed

[Examples of default/fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp)

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints)

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate these values with an XSD processor, that's not its job. But it's very easy to do with XSLT.